# How do we use RMA module of Magento? Is there any book or manual to get hang of Magento?

Tags: magento-1, backend, rma

How do we use RMA module of Magento?

Is there any book or manual to get hang of Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good source available for learn magento basics.You can start from good source available by magento : http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html. And Technical document : https://magento.com/resources/technical And MagentoU offer some free and paid course and video tutorials :https://u.magento.com/

You can also find some good blogs by other website. As you mention for RMA you can see some good post here : http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-enterprise-return-management-authorization-rma/

And on official site :http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/order-processing/rma-workflow.html

Hope it will help.